# Intersect Tool Input Order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersect

To give context, I was using the Intersect Tool to find the number parcels that are located in multiple Sections of an STR.  I tried both the Geoprocessing Tool, and calling the function in ArcPy.  I noticed I got different results when my input was the same order for both methods, Parcel Layer first, then Section layer. However when I did  Parcel Layer first, Section Layer second for the Geoprocessing Intersect Tool, then Section first, Parcel Second with the ArcPy Function, I obtained the same results.

Does order matter with the Intersect Tool?

I figure either it does, or I was just doing something wrong in my ArcPy script that was giving inconsistent results.

Comment: No, I don't think order matters. Either way the intersection is the area that is *common* to both feature classes. Either way the output is the lowest dimension geometry of the inputs... I think the only difference is the order of fields in the output, but it's not good practice to index fields arbitrarily so that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [How Intersect works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-intersect-analysis-works.htm) help:

> When multiple feature classes or layers are specified in the list of
>   input features, the order of the entries in the list does not affect
>   the output feature type, but the spatial reference of the top entry on
>   the tool dialog box (the first entry in scripting) in the list will be
>   used during processing and set to the output.

I think the answer to your question will be that the order may matter if your inputs do not all share the same coordinate system.